# Have I damaged my multimeter by applying voltage in resistance mode?

Tags: voltage, resistance, multimeter, capacitance, damage

I have an VC97 digital multimeter. In resistance mode, I applied the multimeter leads to a battery with a 4.2V charge. I did this twice, and also did so in capacitance mode.

I didn't notice any smoke, and the multimeter seems to function fine on all modes.

I don't understand how applying a voltage in resistance mode may damage the multimeter, and I don't know how to determine if the multimeter is damaged. Can anyone please help?

(Also I promise to read the manual first from now on. Promise.)

Comment: "multimeter seems to function fine on all modes" - that is probably your answer :).

Comment: If it can accurately measure resistance, voltage, and current, then it's not damaged. Compare it to another multimeter, or known parts/values. As far as Capacitance? I don't know if your meter actually has a capacitance meter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When multimeters are in resistance testing mode, they connect their battery to the output through a high resistance (maybe in the order of 200kOhm if not higher), and then measure the effect that the load has on the voltage - if the load is very high resistance, it will read close to the full supply voltage, if the load is very low resistance, it will read close to zero.

What this means is that if you connect a voltage source to the input in this mode, it should do no harm at all (unless it is out of range of what the DMM is specified for, which 4V or so definitely wont be) because the high resistance of the internal voltage source will limit any current flow.

TL;DR; no you won't have done any damage.

---

Update:

Even though this is the schematic of a fluke 87 multimeter, yours will likely be very similar. I've highlighted the switches that are closed for resistance measuring mode, and also for reference the high resistances that are protecting the input (and will mean you have not done any damage):

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Tom, thank you very much for the detailed and concise answer. I appreciate how you walked me through the effect the resistors have on protecting the multimeter from damage.